# Emacs - Ubuntu initialization

Tags: emacs, ubuntu

Odd behavior loading emacs on ubuntu, there seems to be some initialization that goes on that is not in the .emacs nor in any of the files emacs reports loading through "emacs --debug-init". I've found some references to font-related resizing but this behavior doesn't seem to be limited to that (e.g reappearing menus and toolbars).

Does anyone have any additional information about the emacs initialization process?
Does it load /etc/emacs/site-start.d  files before or after the .emacs, and are there any other locations it loads by default?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sequence of the Emacs initialization is the following (at least, for Emacs 22):

1. Load the file *debian-startup* (.el or .elc) found in *load-path* (usually, */usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/debian-startup.el* or */usr/share/emacs22/site-lisp/debian-startup.elc*) and call the function *debian-startup* defined in this file.  This function loads all files in */etc/emacs/site-start.d/* and */etc/emacs22/site-start.d/*.
2. Load *site-start* (.el or .elc) found in *load-path*.
3. Load your init file *.emacs*, *.emacs.el* or *~/.emacs.d/init.el*.
4. Load a default init file *default.el* or *default.elc*.

I also suggest you reading the section "**Emacs startup strategy**" in */usr/share/doc/emacsen-common/debian-emacs-policy.gz* for more Ubuntu/Debian specific information. To find the reason of odd behavior you can start emacs with the argument *--no-site-file* and load these init files one by one until you find a file that causes this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I've found this official document that introduces the emacs init steps:
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

> When Emacs is started, it normally tries to load a Lisp program from an initialization file, or init file for short. This file, if it exists, specifies how to initialize Emacs for you. Emacs looks for your init file using the filenames ~/.emacs, ~/.emacs.el, or ~/.emacs.d/init.el; you can choose to use any one of these three names (see [Find Init](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html#Find-Init)). Here, ~/ stands for your home directory.