# What files Emacs load by default

Tags: emacs

I have weird error when I run Emacs it show u when I run Emacs normaly but not when I run `emacs -q` and then load .emacs by hand using load-file.

So my question is what other files Emacs may load on Init?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs - Ubuntu initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189291/emacs-ubuntu-initialization)

Answer (score 0):

Documented in the manual at:
<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>`(emacs) Init File` <kbd>RET</kbd>